# Magento2: How to add different custom css file on specific CMS pages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0.2, cms-pages

I tried so may things but unable to add the CSS & JS files for each Static CMS pages.
I know if CSS can be added in `cms_page_view.xml` but this will reflect in all pages.

is there anyway to add different CSS files for different static pages.

Answer (score 5):

You can add Layout Update XML update

```
GOTO ADMIN -> Content -> Pages -> Edit page -> Design -> Layout Update XML
```

With the content :

```
<head>
  <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/styles.css"/>
</head>
```

Then there is a bug in Magento 2, you need to override the default Magento 2 `vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd` validation file.

**A workaround, not a clean solution, but waiting Magento 2 to allow override xsd files**

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Layout\Update\Validator" />
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/page_layout.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/head.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/body.xsd"/>

    <xs:complexType name="pageLayoutType">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="referenceContainer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="container" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="update" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="move" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="head" type="headType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="body" type="bodyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="layout" type="pageLayoutType">
        <xs:unique name="containerKey">
            <xs:selector xpath=".//container"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php**

```
<?php
namespace Hublot\Setup\Model\Layout\Update;

use Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\UrnResolver;

class Validator extends \Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator
{
    const LAYOUT_SCHEMA_PAGE_HANDLE = 'page_layout';

    const LAYOUT_SCHEMA_MERGED = 'layout_merged';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory $domConfigFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\UrnResolver $urnResolver
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory $domConfigFactory,
        UrnResolver $urnResolver
    ) {
        $this->_domConfigFactory = $domConfigFactory;
        $this->_initMessageTemplates();
        $this->_xsdSchemas = [
            self::LAYOUT_SCHEMA_PAGE_HANDLE => $urnResolver->getRealPath(
                'urn:hublot:module:Hublot_Setup:etc/page_layout.xsd'
            ),
            self::LAYOUT_SCHEMA_MERGED => $urnResolver->getRealPath(
                'urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_merged.xsd'
            ),
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference to see when this is eventually fixed, this is the Magento bug in question: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4454

Comment: It is indeed a bug I have same issue 2.2.2 there is the fix :https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/822c6e993e1c31aeb9d3c6f49a5ac03b11d21e04

Comment: What is the full path to "Namespace_YourModule::css/" ?

Answer (score 3):

Please follow below steps to add css and js to specific cms page using custom module.

1) Create custom module using below step

> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
  </config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/custom.css
>   Then add your css code into custom.css file

2) GOTO ADMIN -> Content -> Pages -> Edit page -> Design -> Layout Update XML and add below code for particulate page.

```
<head>
   <css src="Vendor_Module::css/custom.css"/>
</head>
```

For the other cms page create specific css file and add `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/` and add that css file into other cms page same as step2 via just changing css file name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You can add custom  css like below:**
**make an entry in layout file**

```
 <page>   
        <head>
                <css src="css/ie-9.css" ie_condition="IE 9" />
                <css src="Magento_Catalog::css/custom.css" />
                <css src="Custom_SampleModule::css/custom.css"/>
            </head>
   </page>
```

Comment: What is the full path to 'Magento_Catalog::css/custom.css' or 'Custom_SampleModule::css/custom.css'

Answer (score 0):

I found that Franck Garnier's does not quite work on 2.1.16.

I had to change the last file, Validator.php, a bit to get it to work as follows.

```
namespace Vendor\CmsLayoutFix\Model\Layout\Update;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\UrnResolver;
use Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Config\ValidationStateInterface;

class Validator extends \Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator
{
    const LAYOUT_SCHEMA_PAGE_HANDLE = 'page_layout';

    const LAYOUT_SCHEMA_MERGED = 'layout_merged';

    private $validationState;

    public function __construct(
        DomFactory $domConfigFactory,
        UrnResolver $urnResolver,
        ValidationStateInterface $validationState = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($domConfigFactory, $urnResolver);
        $this->_xsdSchemas = [
            self::LAYOUT_SCHEMA_PAGE_HANDLE => $urnResolver->getRealPath(
                'urn:vendor:module:Vendor_CmsLayoutFix:etc/page_layout.xsd'
            ),
            self::LAYOUT_SCHEMA_MERGED => $urnResolver->getRealPath(
                'urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_merged.xsd'
            ),
        ];
    }
}
```

WHERE:

vendor = Vendor

module = CmsLayoutFix

Answer (score -1):

In magento all CMS pages have an option of Layout Update XML update .Just Call your Custom code there also add CSS or JS .

Admin CMS Pages

```
GOTO ADMIN -> Content -> Pages -> Edit page -> Design -> Layout Update XML
```

add below call

```
<head>
  <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/styles.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: this works in page layout configuration not in Layout Update XML , hope you checked...

Comment: It is working fine I have tested this code . just remove "Namespace_YourModule::" and set in to "Layout Update XML" and refresh you Cache so you can show in that page only.

Comment: `Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'head': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move ). Line: 1`

this we will get if we put anything else apart from above four Element. 
I am using magento 2.0.7

Comment: Yeah, this worked for me. Just remember to flush the cache after you change the layout for the cms page to pickup the change.

Comment: What is "Namespace_YourModule" is it my custom theme? 
I already extended Luma theme but I do not have any specific module.