# Magento2 details page image once appear and after that disappear

Tags: magento2

I am trying to figure out the issue that image once appear when load first time and after 2 to 3 seconds it disappear.

Please check screenshot with inspect element.

First time when it appear

[image]

Now after complete loading of page image disappeared
[image]

Comment: Try to switch to the luma theme and then check. do you find the issue for any specific product types i.e. simple, configurable?

Comment: Did you find any solution for that. Because i'm also face same. But when i change to luma theme its works perfect

Answer (score 2):

It is a common issue with fotoroma image gallery with bootstrap in magento 2. To solve this problem just need to add below css code in your css.
.gallery-placeholder{ width: 100%; }

Please don't forget to remove the static content and clean the cache.
I had this problem and overcome with that code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have overrided :

```
view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml
```

or 
`etc/view.xml`

Usually this happens with modifications made on custom theme overidde , especially on `etc/view.xml`  .
Try locally to update those based on magento core files . 
Do :

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
rm -rf generated/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I tried these commands but didn't work.

Comment: i remember that i made changes at addtocart.phtml file which i undo and replaced with original luma theme file. Now i run commands again but still same issue

Comment: Is this issue happened after upgrade of magento ? What version of magento do you have ?

Comment: i didn't noticed but it was working before. I think happened after upgrade. Magento 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

this is bug in magento

check this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10687

Open root/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php

```
protected function processMediaGallery(ProductInterface $product, $mediaGalleryEntries)
{
find : if (isset($entry['value_id']) // near line no : 499
TO
if (isset($entry['value_id']) && $entry['value_id'] != '') {
}
```

Comment: Didn't work....

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a lazy-loader that is active on your webshop.
I would need to check this in browser but something is actively changing your image source after page load.

What a lazy loader should do is paste the content of the image (or a placeholder) as the source and then after load replace the source this with the url so the image is fetched after page load which benefits loading times and makes sure the image is loaded asynchronously.

With the screenshots provided i guess that it provides the wrong content and the url is replaced with the content and the url itself is empty resulting in an image before the page is fully loaded and the url is empty after page load resulting in the removal of the image element.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue in Magento 2.4.0 and I was surprised as it was with some of the products only.

Finally I found that I've added a bootstrap js in current custom theme and version is Bootstrap v4.3.1. Its working perfect after removing this js.

Comment: which js do you removed?

Comment: Can you please share how do you remove it ?

Comment: bootstrap.js I've removed which was added by custom theme in my case. to remove specific js follow this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/283652/27583. please upvote answer if that was the answer of what you are looking for. Thanks.